# Details don't match amount total when using taxes

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using Paypal to process payments.

The subtotal (without taxes) for the purchase is 132.94$. My customers are in Canada and I need to multiply a tax percent to that subtotal in order to get the real total.

The tax percent is **1.14975**, but Paypal doesn't accept a tax percent with more than two decimals, so it rounds it to **1.15**.

Here's the code that I use to setup the payment :

```
// Not shown- create an ItemList, add Item's to it
// ...

$details = new Details;
$details->setSubtotal(132.94);
$details->setTax(1.14975);

$amount = new Amount;
$amount->setCurrency('CAD');
$amount->setTotal(152.88); // 132.94 * 1.15
$amount->setDetails($details);

// ...
// Not shown - create the transaction, try to create the payment
```

However, when I try to send the information to Paypal, I get this error :

> Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to specified amount total

I tried dumping out `$amount` to see what it contains, and here's what I see :

[image]

Why does it tell me that the details don't add up to the amount? Am I missing something here? If I multiply the subtotal by the tax, I get the total for the amount, they do match up.

Comment: `132.94 + 1.15` doesn't equal `152.88`. Do you maybe need to `->setTax()` the absolute tax amount in `CAD`?.

Comment: `132.94 + 1.15 != 152.88` I am guessing you have passed the tax rate to the amount of tax field, hense the tax percent error.

Comment: *Facepalm* - Thanks guy, I was certain that I needed to pass the tax rate adn not the amount. It works when I pass the amount instead. If one of you want to post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Hehe. I managed to beat @RiggsFolly for once. ;)

Comment: @jhmckimm :) Well now I know there is a competition I will try harder next time. ;)